# How I can get element from set in clojure?

Tags: arrays, clojure, element

I have set

```
(def tableOfStates [{:_ '\a :q0 'q1 :q1 'q1 :q2 'q3 :q3 '\_ }
                    {:_ '\b :q0 'q2 :q1 'q3 :q2 'q2 :q3 '\_}
                    {:_ '\c :q0 'q3 :q1 'q3 :q2 '\_ :q3 '\_}
                    {:_ '\$ :q0 '\_ :q1 '\_ :q2 '\_ :q3 'pass}])
```

And I want get element this way

```
((get tableOfStates 0) ":q0")
```

But returns `nil`

How can I make this?

Comment: you are passing a string `":q0"`, while your desired content is `:q0` - a keyword. try  `((get tableOfStates 0) :q0)`

Comment: also you can use `get-in` instead of `get`: `(get-in tableOfStates [0 :q0])`. By the way, the contents of your vector are not sets, but hash maps

Comment: I know it, but my goal it's get element when I have only one string ":q0"

Comment: then you should make a keyword of it: `((get tableOfStates 0) (keyword (subs ":q0" 1)))` or like this: `((get tableOfStates 0) (clojure.edn/read-string ":q0"))`

Comment: thanks, this works for me

Comment: @leetwinski there is no need to use `subs` here, or `read-string` (the latter is particularly un-idiomatic). see my answer.

Comment: i know, but i was answering considering the exact ":q0" from the question. Also, as far as i know, `clojure.edn/read-string` (not `clojure.core/read-string`) *is* the safe and idiomatic way to convert a keyword-form string to an actual keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(get-in tableOfStates [0 :q0])`

This returns the value you are looking for, which is the value associated with the key `:q0` of the first element in the vector.

If you must work with a string, do this:

`(get-in tableOfStates [0 (keyword "q0")])`

This converts the string to a keyword first.

From the REPL:

```
> tableOfStates
[{:_ \a, :q0 q1, :q1 q1, :q2 q3, :q3 \_}
 {:_ \b, :q0 q2, :q1 q3, :q2 q2, :q3 \_}
 {:_ \c, :q0 q3, :q1 q3, :q2 \_, :q3 \_}
 {:_ \$, :q0 \_, :q1 \_, :q2 \_, :q3 pass}]
> (get-in tableOfStates [0 :q0])
q1
> (keyword "str")
:str
> (get-in tableOfStates [0 (keyword "q0")])
q1
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more neatly - and faster - if you change the `tableOfStates`, a [state transition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_transition_table), from a *vector of map*s to a *map of maps*:

```
(def tableOfStates {'\a {:q0 'q1 :q1 'q1 :q2 'q3 :q3 '\_}
                    '\b {:q0 'q2 :q1 'q3 :q2 'q2 :q3 '\_}
                    '\c {:q0 'q3 :q1 'q3 :q2 '\_ :q3 '\_}
                    '\$ {:q0 '\_ :q1 '\_ :q2 '\_ :q3 'pass}})
```

We use it like this:

```
((get tableOfStates \a) :q0) ;q1
```

... or just

```
((tableOfStates \a) :q0) ;q1
```

... since a map works as its own `get` function.

We use `\a` directly. We don't have to look for it with the `:_` key.

I think you are under the impression that *keys* have to be *keywords*, and vice versa. Not so! As things are, the states are represented differently depending on what role they play:

- As keys, they are *keywords* `:q0`, `:q1`, `:q2`, and `:q3`.
- As values, they are the corresponding *symbols* `'q0`, `'q1` `'q2`, and `'q3`.
- The (I assume) failed state is represented by the *character* `\_`. (There is no need to quote characters, by the way).

Let's represent them all as *keywords*. The table becomes ...

```
(def tableOfStates {\a {:q0 :q1, :q1 :q1, :q2, :q3, :q3 :_}
                    \b {:q0 :q2, :q1 :q3, :q2 :q2, :q3 :_}
                    \c {:q0 :q3, :q1 :q3, :q2 :_, :q3 :_}
                    \$ {:q0 :_, :q1 :_, :q2 :_, :q3 :pass}})
```

---

*Other changes.*

Use `nil` instead of `:_` to represent the *fail* state. Then you don't need the failing transitions:

```
(def tableOfStates {\a {:q0 :q1, :q1 :q1, :q2 :q3}
                    \b {:q0 :q2, :q1 :q3, :q2 :q2}
                    \c {:q0 :q3, :q1 :q3}
                    \$ {:q3 :pass}})
```

For example,

```
((tableOfStates \$) :q0) ;nil
```

It looks as though `\$` represents *end of input*. If this is supplied, good and well. If not, you might do better to test the final state with the set `#{:q3}`.